# Lock delete () function - Django

Tags: django, django-models

Is there an option to disable the delete function in the project object if a non-admin user tries to do this via delete function?

For example:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=200)
    show = models.BooleanField()
    logs = models.TextField()
```

And now if we have in code of project `product.delete()` we block it through the model property and check if it is an admin, if it is not an admin add a reflection in the field.:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=200)
    show = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    logs = models.TextField()

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if request.user.is_superuser
            Product.delete()
        else:
            show = False
            logs = 'ther user try remove this ads in time: 08.11 04.11.2022'
            save()
```

Comment: are you getting any error here after adding delete function

Comment: My function is an example to illustrate what I mean. I will try to update it with a question after reading the django documentation. However, I did not find a similar question on this page. And this is a very desirable action in many projects. If the previous programmer had created a delete () function, changing the code for the entire project would be a painstaking process. It is better to override the function in my opinion. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the responsibility of the view to check that the user (in `request.user`) has sufficient privilege to perform the requested operation. There's no standard way for a Django object method to obtain the current user, and a programmer with access through the Django shell `>>> obj.delete()` has to be prevented by other means (such as the risk of losing his job). There simply is no Django logged-in user in that context, but the DB to which it has access ought not to be a production one.

Out on a limb, it is  possible to disable the object's `delete()` method completely by subclassing it to a no-op or to raise an exception. Deleting such an object would then require other means. Either relying on a CASCADE when some other object was deleted, or using raw SQL (the psql command, if PostgreSQL) to remove its data row from the DB table.

(I haven't done the latter, but there are certain objects in the project I am working on which should never require deletion under any normal circumstances, and for which there are no delete views or similar. They will accumulate at the rate of around one per week in production, and removing ones which are completely stale is a problem which can safely be deferred until the year 2100 or later :-)